# ReactJS - Auth weird behavior of not able to login until I refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, authentication, local-storage

For Auth Provider, I've added following code: https://gist.github.com/sujit-baniya/e03ba25858d92dc4d198533d6889a82a

Scenario:
I can login in new tab and store the data in localstorage and redirects me to dashboard. But the issue happens after I logout of the application and try to re-login. The response is received from server for logged in user but it doesn't redirects me to dashboard. I've to refresh the page to re-login.

Code snippet:

```
const logout = () => {
    auth
        .logout()
        .then((_response: any) => {
            setLoggedIn(false);
            setLoggedOut(true);
            auth.setAuthUser(null);
            userStore.setUser(null);
            secureLocalStorage.clear()
            // Navigate me to login after logout
            // Cannot re-login until page is refreshed
            navigate("/login?loggedOut=true");
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            console.info("Failed to logout user: %o", error);
            throw error;
        });
};
const login = (user?: User) => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("auth-key") && user) {
        auth.setAuthUser(Object.setPrototypeOf(user, User.prototype));
        userStore.setUser(Object.setPrototypeOf(user, User.prototype));
        setLoggedIn(true);
        setLoggedOut(false);
    }
    navigate("/");
};
```

I'm not sure what is going on and how could I fix this issue. I would appreciate any help